# How to duplicate a set of rows changing only the value of one column without listing the other columns?

Tags: database, oracle

Given a table `T(x, y, z, t, u, v, ...)` is it possible in Oracle to write this query **without listing all columns** (be it in the SELECT or in the INSERT part)?

```
INSERT INTO T (x, y, z, t, u, v, ...)
SELECT 'new', y, z, t, u, v, ...
  FROM T
 WHERE x = 'old'
```

The effect is that all rows for which `x` has the value of *old* are duplicated, except that now `x` has the value of *new*.

Comment: @Hugh Jones: Of course, INSERTING without listing a column will insert the default value. I want to duplicate existing rows.

Comment: The query you show above will have exactly the effect you are looking for.

Comment: @Hugh Jones: I want to avoid listing all columns, and telling me “list all columns” is not an answer!

Comment: @NullUserException ఠ_ఠ: PLSQL answers are welcome then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "is it possible in Oracle to write this query without listing all
>   columns (be it in the SELECT or in the INSERT part)"

No.  The only way to avoid typing an explicit projection is to use all the table's columns.  You aren't doing that, because you want to use a literal instead of column `X`.  That means you have to list all the other columns in the SELECT projection.

Of course, you don't have to specify the columns in the INSERT clause.

Over the years developers have occasionally wished for an "except" syntax, something like:

```
select * except X from t
```

but it's never made it into the ANSI standard.  In fact, I doubt if it's even been discussed.

---

> "PLSQL answers are welcome then!"

Okay, here is a proof of concept which uses the data dictionary to produce a dynamic insert statement.

It makes the following assumptions:

1. You only want to substitute the value of one column.
2. The column you want to substitute is a string datatype.
3. You want to clone all the records in the source table.

You will need to adjust the code if any of those assumptions are wrong.

The procedure loops round the USER_TAB_COLUMNS table, sorting the columns into the table's  projected order.  It concatenates the column names into the SELECT clause of an INSERT statement, except where the name is that of the substituted column when it concatenates the provided literal instead.  Finally it uses Native Dynamic SQL to run the assembled INSERT statement.

```
create or replace procedure clone_minus_one 
    ( p_sub_col in user_tab_columns.column_name%type
      , p_sub_val in varchar2 )
is
    stmt varchar2(32767) := 'insert into source_table select ';
begin
    for lrec in ( select column_name
                         , column_position 
                  from  user_tab_columns.
                  where table_name = 'SOURCE_TABLE'
                  order by column_position )
    loop
        if lrec.column_position != 1
        then 
            stmt := stmt ||',';
        end if;
        if lrec.column_name != p_sub_col
        then
            stmt := stmt ||lrec.column_name;
        else
            stmt := stmt ||''''||p_sub_val||'''';
        end if;  
    end loop;
    stmt := stmt || ' from source_table';
    execute immediate stmt;
end;
/
```

Comment: thank you! Will try. Might I edit that answer if I improve it?

Comment: @Benoit - knock yourself out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly as you describe, provided your selected columns are ordered correctly.

The following is Valid

```
INSERT INTO T 
SELECT 'new', y, z, t, u, v, ...
  FROM T
 WHERE x = 'old'
```

or you could try this (Rough script not tested)

```
CREATE TABLE TEMPTABLE AS SELECT * FROM T WHERE X = 'Old';

UPDATE TEMPTABLE SET X='New';

INSERT INTO T (SELECT * FROM TEMPTABLE);

DROP TABLE TEMPTABLE;
```

Comment: You have to list all the columns you want in the select, but provided they map to the columns in the correct order the query will work.

Comment: @Hugh Jones: OK, question reformulated: I want to avoid listing all columns in the INSERT part and listing all columns but x in the SELECT part. Wasn't that clear enough?

Comment: Was I being pedantic ? Sorry.

Comment: I think creating a temporary table just to avoid some *typing* is over-engineering at its worst.

Comment: @APC - I suspect the poster is after a rather more generic solution

Answer (score 0):

The following is going too far to avoid some typing imo, but I like a challenge, so here it goes...

```
insert into T
select * from T
where x='old';
commit;

-- update every other row to 'new'
update T
set x='new'
where rowid in
(
select rowid from
  (select rownum rnum, rowid row_id
   from T
   where x='old'
  )
where mod(rnum,2)=0
);
commit;
```

In 2 steps, but personally I'd just query all_tab_columns for the table (order by column_id) and copy/paste into my script/procedure.  But may be some other reason to avoid this, not sure.

Comment: Thank you, this seems clever but 1. there could be unique constraints (alas), 2. order of rownum assignment is never guaranteed so you cannot reliably assume that every second row is a newly inserted row except if you ORDER BY * (haha, need to list all columns here!)

Comment: yes, sorry benoit, thats correct, this answer won't work reliably with the...order by.  trying to be too clever I guess ;)